# Parse JSON block with dynamic variables

Tags: c#, json

I'm grabbing JSON object from an URL and parsing it with JSON.NET.  I was able to parse blocks of data with defined variables just fine, but when it comes to random collection of var:value - i'm stuck.

Example(loosely typed):

`{"FNAME":"joe","LNAME":"doe",

"BodyType":{"height":180,"weight":"200","race":"white","hair":"black"},

"BELONGINGS":{"shirt":"black","Money":15,"randomThing":"anyvar"},

"Signs":{"tattoo":0,"scar":"forehead","glasses":"dorky"}

}`

I'm casting this to

`Class Person

{

 public string FNAME;

 public string LNAME;

 public BodyType bodyType;

 public ????? belongings;

 public ????? signs;

}`


How do I handle belongings and signs if i cannot predict their properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, they're sure to be JSON objects, right, and JSON objects are associative arrays mapping strings to something.  So I'd represent them as `Dictionary<string, dynamic>` -- a map of strings to somethings.

Answer (score 8):

There's two ways of handling them without knowing the contents at runtime.

The first way is to use JSON.Net's `JObject`, which will handle the case you've mentioned, plus hierarchies.

The second way is to use System.Dynamic's `ExpandoObject`, which is newly supported by recent releases of JSON.Net. Unfortunately it doesn't quite handle hierarchies, but JSON.Net falls back onto `JObject` to support them when encountered. For your purposes, it might be more straightforward.

Here's an example with the snippet and definitions you've given. Also note that `ExpandoObject` is directly castable to `IDictionary<string, object>`, whereas `JObject` has explicit methods to access properties.

Person corresponds to `ExpandoObject`, and JPerson corresponds to `JObject`.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using System.Dynamic;

using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

namespace YourFavoriteNamespace
{
    public class JPerson
    {
        public string FNAME;
        public string LNAME;
        public BodyType bodyType;
        public JObject belongings;
        public JObject signs;
    }

    public class Person
    {
        public string FNAME;
        public string LNAME;
        public BodyType bodyType;
        public ExpandoObject belongings;
        public ExpandoObject signs;
    }

    public class BodyType
    {
        public int height;
        public int weight;
        public string race;
        public string hair;
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void DumpDynamic(dynamic d)
        {
            IDictionary<string, object> dynMap = (IDictionary<string, object>)d;
            foreach (string key in dynMap.Keys)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("  {0}={1} (type {2})", key, dynMap[key], null == dynMap[key] ? "null" : dynMap[key].GetType().Name);
            }
        }

        static void DumpJProperties(JObject jo)
        {
            var props = jo.Properties();
            foreach (JProperty prop in props)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("  {0}={1} (type {2})", prop.Name, prop.Value, null == prop.Value ? "null" : prop.Value.GetType().Name);
            }
        }

        static void DumpPerson(Person p)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Person");
            Console.WriteLine("  FNAME={0}", p.FNAME);
            Console.WriteLine("  LNAME={0}", p.LNAME);
            Console.WriteLine("Person.BodyType");
            Console.WriteLine("  height={0}", p.bodyType.height);
            Console.WriteLine("  weight={0}", p.bodyType.weight);
            Console.WriteLine("  race  ={0}", p.bodyType.race);
            Console.WriteLine("  hair  ={0}", p.bodyType.hair);
            Console.WriteLine("Person.belongings");
            DumpDynamic(p.belongings);
            Console.WriteLine("Person.signs");
            DumpDynamic(p.signs);
        }

        static void DumpJPerson(JPerson p)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Person");
            Console.WriteLine("  FNAME={0}", p.FNAME);
            Console.WriteLine("  LNAME={0}", p.LNAME);
            Console.WriteLine("Person.BodyType");
            Console.WriteLine("  height={0}", p.bodyType.height);
            Console.WriteLine("  weight={0}", p.bodyType.weight);
            Console.WriteLine("  race  ={0}", p.bodyType.race);
            Console.WriteLine("  hair  ={0}", p.bodyType.hair);
            Console.WriteLine("Person.belongings");
            DumpJProperties(p.belongings);
            Console.WriteLine("Person.signs");
            DumpJProperties(p.signs);
        }

        static void DoSimplePerson()
        {
            string initJson = "{\"FNAME\":\"joe\",\"LNAME\":\"doe\",\"BodyType\":{\"height\":180,\"weight\":\"200\",\"race\":\"white\",\"hair\":\"black\"},\"BELONGINGS\":{\"shirt\":\"black\",\"Money\":15,\"randomThing\":\"anyvar\"},\"Signs\":{\"tattoo\":0,\"scar\":\"forehead\",\"glasses\":\"dorky\"}}";
            Person p = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person>(initJson);
            DumpPerson(p);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static void DoComplexPerson()
        {
            string initJson = "{\"FNAME\":\"joe\",\"LNAME\":\"doe\",\"BodyType\":{\"height\":180,\"weight\":\"200\",\"race\":\"white\",\"hair\":\"black\"},\"BELONGINGS\":{\"shirt\":\"black\",\"Money\":15,\"randomThing\":\"anyvar\"},\"Signs\":{\"tattoo\":0,\"scar\":\"forehead\",\"glasses\":[\"dorky\",\"hipster\"]}}";
            Person p = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person>(initJson);
            DumpPerson(p);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static void DoJPerson()
        {
            string initJson = "{\"FNAME\":\"joe\",\"LNAME\":\"doe\",\"BodyType\":{\"height\":180,\"weight\":\"200\",\"race\":\"white\",\"hair\":\"black\"},\"BELONGINGS\":{\"shirt\":\"black\",\"Money\":15,\"randomThing\":\"anyvar\"},\"Signs\":{\"tattoo\":0,\"scar\":\"forehead\",\"glasses\":\"dorky\"}}";
            JPerson p = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JPerson>(initJson);
            DumpJPerson(p);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DoSimplePerson();
            DoComplexPerson();
            DoJPerson();
        }
    }
}
```