# How do I incrementally serialize and deserialize JSON with ServiceStack?

Tags: c#, json, .net-3.5, servicestack

What I have is this:

```
string json = @"{'number': 3, 'object' : { 't' : 3, 'whatever' : 'hi', 'str': 'test'}";
```

How do I read the fields until I'm at 'object', then serialize the whole 'object' into a .NET type and then continue parsing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your types:

```
public class Object
{
    public int t { get; set; }
    public string whatever { get; set; }
    public string str { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public int number { get; set; }
    public Object object { get; set; }
}
```

Then just deserialize it:

```
string json = @"{'number': 3, 'object' : { 't' : 3, 'whatever' : 'hi', 'str': 'test'}";
var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
//do what you want
```

**UPDATE**

You didn't say it's dynamic, for such parsing there is many solutions.

Check the following:

[Using JSON.NET for dynamic JSON parsing](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2012/Aug/30/Using-JSONNET-for-dynamic-JSON-parsing)

[Using C# 4.0 and dynamic to parse JSON](http://www.drowningintechnicaldebt.com/ShawnWeisfeld/archive/2010/08/22/using-c-4.0-and-dynamic-to-parse-json.aspx)

[Deserialize JSON into C# dynamic object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142495/deserialize-json-into-c-sharp-dynamic-object)

[Parse JSON block with dynamic variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5628374/parse-json-block-with-dynamic-variables)

[Turning JSON into a ExpandoObject](http://coderjournal.com/2010/07/turning-json-into-a-expandoobject/)

To handle a dynamic type: use `dynamic`, to handle dynamic data such as **XML** or **JSON** use `ExpandoObject`.

**UPDATE 2**

[Using Anonymous types to deserialize JSON data](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexghi/archive/2008/12/22/using-anonymous-types-to-deserialize-json-data.aspx)

**UPDATE 3**

Will this work for you:

```
 string json = "{\"number\": 3, \"object\" : { \"t\" : 3, \"whatever\" : \"hi\", \"str\": \"test\"}}";
            var deserialized = SimpleJson.DeserializeObject<IDictionary<string, object>>(json);

            var yourObject = deserialized["object"] as IDictionary<string, object>;            
            if (yourObject != null)
            {
                var tValue = yourObject.GetValue("t");
                var whateverValue = yourObject.GetValue("whatever");
                var strValue = yourObject.GetValue("str");
            } 

 public static object GetValue(this IDictionary<string,object> yourObject, string propertyName)
        {
            return yourObject.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Key == propertyName).Value;
        }
```

Final result:

[image]

Or change to the following

```
if (yourObject != null)
            {
                foreach (string key in yourObject.Keys)
                {
                    var myValue = yourObject.GetValue(key);
                }
            }
```

[image]

**UPDATE 4 - SERVICE STACK**

```
string json = "{\"number\": 3, \"object\" : { \"t\" : 3, \"whatever\" : \"hi\", \"str\": \"test\"}}";
            var deserialized = JsonObject.Parse(json);

            var yourObject = deserialized.Get<IDictionary<string, object>>("object");

            if (yourObject != null)
            {
                foreach (string key in yourObject.Keys)
                {
                    var myValue = yourObject.GetValue(key);
                }
            }
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I don't know the type, the json string could be anything - that's the entire point of why I need to do it incrementally. I want to peek at the key, and then get the corresponding value. This is possible with just about any C json library.

Comment: plurby, my requirement is that it's .NET 3.5 compatible. The dynamic keyword isn't.

Comment: @Blub You should stated this requirement in your question. See my update 2.

Comment: I did, it's a tag. And your link still doesn't actually help me because an anonymous type is still a c# type with all the fields that it has to have. I don't know those fields before serializing the json string.

Comment: Didn't look at the tags. Can't you use https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Razor/Json/DynamicJson.cs ?

Comment: But now you used SimpleJson for it, I wanted it with ServiceStack. It's still useful if I want to switch to SimpleJson, but not right now.

Comment: @Blub Update 4 has ServiceStack example. Please mark as answered.

Comment: I figured it out with your help, the key is to use an IDictionary for serialization, like you did. That even works with Servicestack. (although it adds weird __type things in between). Gonna have to investigate

Comment: What I mean: Serializer.SerializeToString<YourDictionaryTypeWhereYouPutEverything>(obj)

Answer (score 1):

Look at [ServiceStack's Dynamic JSON Parsing](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text#supports-dynamic-json-as-well):

```
var myPoco = JsonObject.Parse(json)
    .GetUnescpaed("object")
    .FromJson<TMyPoco>();
```

Comment: Does not help when I don't know what my parameters are called, and I still don't know how to serialize. JsonObject.WriteValue() is a completely unusable API, no idea what that is even supposed to do.

Comment: @Blub Just iterate over it, JsonObject inherits `Dictionary<string,string>`

Answer (score 0):

This works for deserializing, I will update once I got serializing.

```
foreach(KeyValuePair<String,String> entry in JsonObject.Parse(json))
{

}
```

Edit: Looks like this only works for json objects. I still don't know how to iterate over JsonArrayObjects